Assumption in derivation of force exerted by hose on wall
If a stream of water of density $\rho$ strikes an area $A$ on a wall with velocity $u$ without rebounding, the force exerted on the wall is given by $$F=\rho A u^2$$
The reasoning that I've been taught is as follows:

In a time interval $\Delta t$, a mass $\Delta m=\rho A u\Delta t$ moving at velocity $v$ is brought to rest.
Taking the mass $\Delta m$ as a system, we get $$\vec{\Delta P}=-(\rho A u\Delta t)u\  \hat{i}=-\rho Au^2\Delta t\ \hat{i}$$
By the impulse momentum theorem,
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{\Delta P}&= \Sigma \vec{F} \ \Delta t \\
\frac{\vec{\Delta P}}{\Delta t}&= \Sigma \vec{F} =-F \\
 F&=\rho A u^2
\end{aligned}$$

I am unable to rationalize the assumption that the total external force acting on the mass element is given by $\Sigma \vec{F}=-F$. Are we assuming that the water behind it exerts no force on this element? That assumption seems reasonable enough when all the water is moving at the same velocity, but when the element is being brought to rest, surely the water beind it "pushes" into it, thereby exerting a non-neglibible force on it that must be taken into account.
Edit
Upon further reflection, I have also noticed another implicit assumption in the reasoning above. While it is certainly clear that the mass $\Delta m$ striking the wall in a time $\Delta t$ is given by $\Delta m= \rho A u\Delta t$, I do not think it follows that it is brought to rest over the same time period.

If the end goal is to find the force acting on the wall, then any force between water mass elements will come in N3L pairs, so maybe you can argue that these will not result in a net force on the wall in the end? Anyway, I'm not sure how useful it is to improve/add details to a model like this that is clearly not very realistic to begin with (I washed my terrace yesterday and the water sure did not come to rest when I was cleaning the outside walls hehe).

@MariusLadegårdMeyer The forces between mass elements disappears as action-reaction pairs only when they occur as internal forces, which would require the mass element to consist of the entire stream (which isn't possible, assuming the stream is continuous and extends indefinitely).
Yes, you are right in that this is far form a realistic model, but I would still like to be rigorous about my analysis even if the model is a rather ideal one

The impulse-momentum theorem states that $FΔt=Δ(mv)$
Considering the whole stream of water as a system:
$F=Δmv$ of the stream in unit seconds.
In a second a mass $Δm=ρAv$
moving at velocity $v$
is brought to rest. So, $F=ρAv^2$
The impulse-momentum theorem cannot be applied for $Δm$ as a system (as such in the assumed way) because F is not acting on it throughout the interval (otherwise fluid would be compressible)
Alternative: Considering the whole stream as a system
$F=(dm/dt)   v $
$F=|-ρAv^2 | $

If you consider the whole stream as the system, why don't you take into account the force exerted by whatever is driving the stream of mass at the back end?

No force is required to drive the stream. The force on the wall is acting; its consequence is the change in the system's momentum. Comment for further clarifications.

"The impulse-momentum theorem cannot be applied for
as a system (as such in the assumed way) because F is not acting on it throughout the interval (otherwise fluid would be compressible)" I don't understand this statement. What else is $F$ acting on throughout the interval $\Delta t$ if not $\Delta m=\rho A v \ \Delta t$ ?
